# java.util.NoSuchElementException error while iterating a json

Tags: android

Im trying to parse the following json

```
{
  "status": 1,
  "value": {
    "star1": {
      "0": "Response from Vaighai is good",
      "1": "Shipment process is fine"
    },
    "star2": {
      "0": "Shipment process is fine",
      "1": "Response from Vaighai is good",
      "2": "Shipment status through app is"
    }
  }
}
```

This is the code that Im using

```
JSONObject value = new JSONObject(notificationResponse.getString("value"));
JSONObject starOne = value.getJSONObject("star1");
JSONObject starTwo = value.getJSONObject("star2");

Iterator<String> starOneIterator = starOne.keys();
Iterator<String> starTwoIterator = starTwo.keys();

String starOnestatus = null;
String starOnekey = null;
String starTwostatus = null;
String starTwokey = null;

while (starOneIterator.hasNext()){
    starOnekey = starOneIterator.next();
    starOnestatus = starOne.optString(starOneIterator.next());
}

while (starTwoIterator.hasNext()){
    starTwokey = starTwoIterator.next();
    starTwostatus = starTwo.optString(starTwoIterator.next());
}
```

Im getting the following error message,
`java.util.NoSuchElementException`.. I may not know the key during runtime so Im iterating it within while loop but the error message is getting fired.

Comment: in start object there are objects not array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

`starOnestatus = starOne.optString(starOneIterator.next());`

to

`starOnestatus = starOne.optString(starOnekey);`

The change also applies for the other iteration.

Answer (score 0):

Change this to

```
 JSONObject jObjRoot = new JSONObject(notificationResponse.toString());
    JSONObject jObjvalue = jObjRoot.getJSONObject("value");
    JSONObject starOne = jObjvalue.getJSONObject("star1");
    JSONObject starTwo = jObjvalue.getJSONObject("star2");

Iterator<String> starOneIterator = starOne.keys();
Iterator<String> starTwoIterator = starTwo.keys();

String starOnestatus = null;
String starOnekey = null;
String starTwostatus = null;
String starTwokey = null;

while (starOneIterator.hasNext()){
    starOnekey = starOneIterator.next();
    starOnestatus = starOne.optString(starOneIterator.next());
}

while (starTwoIterator.hasNext()){
    starTwokey = starTwoIterator.next();
    starTwostatus = starTwo.optString(starTwoIterator.next());
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `jObjvalue.getJSONObject("star1");`?

Comment: Oh..I forgot. Thanks for noticing it. Edited now. :)

Comment: starTwoKey and starTwostatus gives null null